# Incorrect UITableViewCell Height with Dynamic UILabels and Content Compression/Resistance

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, uitableview

Building on Xcode 7.2.1, iOS 9.2

I have a `UITableView` with cells that have automatic height.

```
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 80
tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
```

The layout of the cells is as follows:

```
UITableViewCell
  contentView
  outerStackView - pinned to top, left, right, bottom edges of the contentView with autolayout
    leftColumnStackView - 38% of width of outerStackView
       topStackView
         label UILabel
         value UILabel
       bottomStackView
         label UILabel
         value UILabel
    middleColumnStackView - 38% of width of outerStackView
      ...
    rightColumnStackView - rest of the width of outerStackView
      ...
```

The cells have 6 label/value pairs in them -- [Label X: Value]. Each label/value pair is comprised of 2 `UILabels`, with their content hugging and content compressions resistance attributes set accordingly to give the desired look.

```
label.numberOfLines = 0
label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Left
label.setContentCompressionResistancePriority(1000, forAxis: .Horizontal)
label.setContentHuggingPriority(1000, forAxis: .Horizontal)

value.numberOfLines = 0
value.setContentCompressionResistancePriority(500, forAxis: .Horizontal)
value.setContentHuggingPriority(500, forAxis: .Horizontal)

// there are 6 stack views, each containing a label/value pair
// the stack views are .Horizontal alignment, and pinned to the 
// columns they sit in
stackView.addArrangedSubview(label)
stackView.addArrangedSubview(value)
```

However, sometimes the cell height properly measures itself, and other times adds a bunch of extra space (interesting enough, the extra space is always equal to the space that *would* be there if the content compression/hugging wasn't added to either label).

Here's the inconsistency that happens:

Sometimes it's right:
[image]

Sometimes it's wrong:
[image]

When I remove the content compression/resistance from the labels however, the cell is always the correct height, but looks like this:
[image]

Anybody experienced similar? Have any suggestions?

Comment: What do your constraints look like?

Comment: @beyowulf so everything is positioned inside stack views inside of stack views.  1 outer stackview -> 3 columns stackviews inside -> inside each column, 2 stackviews, each with a label/value inside. I can add some embellishment to the question regarding the structure.

Comment: Where are you calling `label.numberOfLines = 0
label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Left
label.setContentCompressionResistancePriority(1000, forAxis: .Horizontal)
label.setContentHuggingPriority(1000, forAxis: .Horizontal) etc.`?

Comment: I'm guessing you are setting the compression and hugging in cellForRowAtIndexPath, which sometimes gets called before the auto layout engine pass and sometimes after I'd try moving it to your UITableViewCell subclass's awakeFromNib.

Comment: @beyowulf, I'm creating my cells programmatically, not with Storyboards. I'm setting the `compression`, `hugging`, `numberOfLines` etc all in the `init()` of the cell, and using `dequeuReusableCellWithIdentifier` for my `UITableView`. Do you think there's an equivalent to awakeFromNib for programatic cell creation?

Comment: No init() is where I would put it. You might try moving it to layoutSubviews(), but I don't have much confidence in that. Where are you setting the pins for the outer stack view?

Answer (score 2):

Figured it out!

This ended up having to do with how the `contentView` of the cell was positioned using AutoLayout. Apparently, by default it was not laying out and calculating the position of its subviews correctly.

In my UITableViewCell subclass, I added the following to my `init()`

```
contentView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
contentView.leadingAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(leadingAnchor).active = true
contentView.trailingAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(trailingAnchor).active = true
contentView.topAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(topAnchor).active = true
contentView.bottomAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(bottomAnchor).active = true
```

By pinning the `contentView` to the cell, the issue of the inconsistent height assignment of that `UITableViewCell` went away, and the correct height was always displayed.

This has resulted in the `contentView` being stretched to all 4 edges, which does effect some other things (like the animation of when a `UITableView` has editing flipped to `true`), but for now I can work around those issues in other ways, since nothing is being calculated as wrong or is happening that's unexpected anymore.